# Best way to implement singleton in MeteorJS

Tags: meteor

My best guess is to use something in a Session, but say you'd want a singleton object which persists across all active sessions? Just getting started with MeteorJS and not finding a *lot* of answers yet on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be shared across browsers and machines, then you should use a Collection and insert/update the singleton value in it. The document will be persisted across sessions which choose to subscribe to it.

However, if meant active sessions in one single browser but possibly separated by tab and time (and you do not want to use the backend), then I would suggest using the `amplify` package and putting that document in the `localStorage`.

Comment: very nice advice! thanks for taking the time to provide this info.

Comment: ah and i just grokked your suggestion about amplify, which looks like a *very* useful package. thanks again.

Comment: @the0ther Glad you found it useful. :)